# How to export data from tweepy, to xlsx?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

i need your help, i am trying to export the data mining by tweepy to an xlsx file by xlsxwriter, but it is giving error. How can I solve?

**EDIT 1:**

(One Solution, by user Eli Lopez)

Its worked, but wrote one line... How to solve this?
Or others solutions?
(There are many tweets caught, I need to export in xlsx.)

This is my code:

```
import json
import csv
import xlsxwriter
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = "my_key"
consumer_secret = "my_key"
access_token = "my_key"
access_token_secret = "my_key"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

def tweet_to_xlsx(tweet):
    tweet_list = []
    tweet_list.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text])
  # tweet_list.append(tweet.text)
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tweet.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    row = 0
    col = 0
    for user, tweet in tweet_list:
        worksheet.write(row, col, user)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, tweet)
        row += 1
    workbook.close()

results = api.search(q=name, lang=lang, count=tweetCount)
for tweet in results:
    print(tweet.user.screen_name, "Twittou:", tweet.text)
    tweet_to_xlsx(tweet)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "extTwitter.py", line 113, in <module>
    tweet_to_xlsx(tweet)
  File "extTwitter.py", line 60, in tweet_to_xlsx
    for user, tweet in tweet_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are appending, you're appending items not lists

```
tweet_list = [USER, TWEET USER, TWEET]
```

what you want is a list of lists

```
tweet_list = [[USER, TWEET], [USER, TWEET]]
```

What your code should be:

```
tweet_list.append([tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text])
# you could also use () instead of [] as tuples are faster
```

Comment: Thanks Eli Lopez, it worked, but only wrote one line. What would be the solution to write all captured tweets?

Comment: @vic.py you would have to save all the tweets in a global list and then you would write to an excel file. What your doing is overwriting the excel file everytime.